# What is a token string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, token, terminology, preprocessor-directive

> The #define creates a macro, which is the association of an identifier
>   or parameterized identifier **with a token string.** After the macro is
>   defined, the compiler can substitute the **token string** for each
>   occurrence of the identifier in the source file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/cpp/preprocessor/hash-define-directive-c-cpp?view=vs-2017

Surprisingly, the question has not been directly asked, rather asking about `tokenization`, `tokenizer`, `tokening` etc. Even searching on DuckDuckGo, the closest question was on quora asking,

> [What is a string token in c++?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-string-token-in-C++)

And it is not obvious to me whether `string token` and `token string` would be synonymous. So just to be clear:

What is a token string in c++?

Comment: The compiler deoes no such thing. That's the job of the preprocessor. If you want to find out what the compiler gets to see after the preprocessro run `gcc -E foo.c`

Comment: The answer to the Quora link was written by someone who appears to have wanted to answer a different question.

Comment: Addendum to @Swordfish 's comment: [The Visual Studio version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/p-preprocess-to-a-file?view=vs-2017)

Comment: And keep an eye out for the Tolkien strings. They're the short ones with hairy feet.

Comment: One (st)ring to rule them all, one (st)ring to find them, One (st)ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them.

Comment: @Swordfish that's... precious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the *token string* is the macro body. In

```
#defined MAKE_MY_FUNC(x) void x(int bar)
```

The `void x(int foo)` part would be considered the *token string* and when you use `MAKE_MY_FUNC` like

```
MAKE_MY_FUNC(foo){ std::cout << bar; }
```

then the *token string* would be subsituted in and the code would be transformed into

```
void foo(int foo){ std::cout << bar; }
```

---

Your article gives you what they call the *token-string* in the second paragraph

> The *token-string* argument consists of a series of tokens, such as keywords, constants, or complete statements. One or more white-space characters must separate *token-string* from *identifier*. This white space is not considered part of the substituted text, nor is any white space that follows the last token of the text.